# SQL / Excel increment values within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL that contains a TreePath that I would like to duplicate and change the values of.
It can look like this: "150/151/156/161" (can be more than 3 numbers too). I want to be able to increment each value with a set amount (that the user should be able to choose). I can export it to Excel and perhaps use vba to set up a solid solution, but I'm quite unexperienced and don't have the time to elaborate.

But can this be done right in SQL, or is Excel the way to go?

The goal of it is to make a duplicate and change the values that separates the new object from the old. Right now I had to use Excel and fetch everything with LEFT, MID and then CONCATENATE after incrementing the value I wanted.

Is something unclear, please ask. Would love for your help.

Thanks in advance. You guys are learning me a lot already.

EDIT:

[image: TreePath]

Each number here - except the first (141) should be incremented by a value that depends on the last ID within SQL. Let's say the last ID right now is 769. So the values needs to be incremented by 628 meaning we want 141/770/795/799/804.

If this can be achieved within SQL or Excel doesn't matter much. I just wish for the process to be quite straightforward.

I've only used formulas to fetch each value into a new cell, incremented it and concatenated it back together.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? Please provide sample data and desired outputs along side with your attempt to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I do mean SQL Server and SSMS. I've updated the post for - I hope - some clarification.

Comment: How do you get to the `628` increment? `779 - 141 = 638` is the closest I can get with your data. Also, wat version of SQL Server are you using (there are some handy string functions starting from version 2016) and are your paths always increasing numbers (`1/2/3` instead of `1/3/2`)?

Comment: Meant 769, not 779 - sorry.
Using SQL Server 2019. SSMS v18.5.
Yes, the numbers are always increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
declare @paths table
(
    MyPath nvarchar(100)
);

insert into @paths (MyPath) values
('141/142/167/171/176'),
('141/142/167/171/177'),
('141/142/167/171/178'),
('141/142/167/171/179'),
('141/142/167/171/180'),
('141/142/167/171/181'),
('141/142/167/171/182'),
('141/142/167/171/183'),
('141/142/167/171/184'),
('141/142/167/171/185'),
('141/142/167/171/186'),
('141/142/167/171/187'),
('141/142/167/171/188'),
('141/142/167/171/189'),
('141/142/167/171/190'),
('141/142/167/171/191'),
('141/142/167/171/192'),
('141/142/167/171/193'),
('100/142/167/171/193'); --will be filtered out

declare @reference int = 769;
```

**Solution**

Uses a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE) to isolate some steps of the process.

Uses the [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function to separate the path parts. This function is non-deterministic (not guaranteed to return the results in the same order). But it has been confirmed that we can explicitly sort on the path part because the numbers are always increasing.

Then use the [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function to merge the paths back together, again with an explicit sort.

```
with cte as
(
    select  p.MyPath,
            convert(int, s.value) as PathPart,
            @reference - min(convert(int, s.value)) over(partition by p.MyPath order by convert(int, s.value)) as Increment,
            case when row_number() over(partition by p.MyPath order by convert(int, s.value)) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as DoIncrement
    from @paths p
    cross apply string_split(p.MyPath, '/') s
    where p.MyPath like '141/%' --filter on target rows
)
select  cte.MyPath,
        string_agg(cte.PathPart + (cte.DoIncrement * cte.Increment), '/') within group (order by cte.PathPart) as NewPath
from cte
group by cte.MyPath;
```

**Result**

```
MyPath               NewPath
-------------------- --------------------
141/142/167/171/176  141/770/795/799/804
141/142/167/171/177  141/770/795/799/805
141/142/167/171/178  141/770/795/799/806
141/142/167/171/179  141/770/795/799/807
141/142/167/171/180  141/770/795/799/808
141/142/167/171/181  141/770/795/799/809
141/142/167/171/182  141/770/795/799/810
141/142/167/171/183  141/770/795/799/811
141/142/167/171/184  141/770/795/799/812
141/142/167/171/185  141/770/795/799/813
141/142/167/171/186  141/770/795/799/814
141/142/167/171/187  141/770/795/799/815
141/142/167/171/188  141/770/795/799/816
141/142/167/171/189  141/770/795/799/817
141/142/167/171/190  141/770/795/799/818
141/142/167/171/191  141/770/795/799/819
141/142/167/171/192  141/770/795/799/820
141/142/167/171/193  141/770/795/799/821
```

---

**Understanding**

Run the following query to understand how the CTE works.

```
select  p.MyPath,
        convert(int, s.value) as PathPart,
        @reference - min(convert(int, s.value)) over(partition by p.MyPath order by convert(int, s.value)) as Increment,
        row_number() over(partition by p.MyPath order by convert(int, s.value)) as PathPartNum,
        case when row_number() over(partition by p.MyPath order by convert(int, s.value)) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as DoIncrement
from @paths p
cross apply string_split(p.MyPath, '/') s;
```

Comment: Thanks Sander! Should probably be able to work out what I'm about to ask. But the column TreePath contains much much that starts with 141/ and also paths that start with other ID's (don't want to touch those). But how to I target the whole column or even better - the selection 'WHERE TreePath LIKE '141/%'. Am I making sense?

Comment: You can filter your data in the CTE, after the `cross apply` line. Working with my column names that would give `where p.MyPath like '141/%'`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being quite slow. But I don't get it work. First time I encounte CTE. Is there something in the code I need to change to make it work?

Comment: I added the filter and an invalid sample row to my answer. You can experiment with it in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8afb557869cfafa90ebd0c5ea790503f).

Comment: Alright, now I see where I was going wrong. I was running everything separably. Right now the values are fixed after 'values' on the sixth row, right? How do I make it take the whole column called 'TreePath' within a table called 'Node'?

Comment: `@paths` is a table variable that keeps me from constantly creating and dropping tables in my test database (it only exists during the query batch execution). This [new fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a48744f53b358a96d158d416c8507f9c) works with an actual table with your names.

Comment: How do I change the strings of values ('141/142/167/171/187'), ('141/142/167/171/188'), etc to iterate a whole column from a table?

Comment: My last fiddle _already_ processes the entire `Node.TreePath` column, it only filters on `Node.TreePath like '141/%'`.

Comment: Node.TreePath is an already existing column with ~1000 rows that I want to search through and alter. Right now it only goes through the eight values that come after 'insert into NodeCopy (TreePath) values'. Sorry if I've been unclear. I can only get it to change the values provided. Perhaps I need to declare a cursor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220981/discussion-between-sander-and-imbalize).